# Go fullscreen with NSWindow on a second screen on macOS 10.12 with Swift 3?

Tags: swift, fullscreen, nswindow

I'm trying to go fullscreen with a second window on a second screen, tho I'm still seeing the menu bar.

This is my code:

```
let second_screen = NSScreen.screens()?[1]
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: (second_screen?.frame)!, styleMask: .fullScreen, backing: .buffered, defer: true, screen: second_screen)
self.window_controller = NSWindowController(window: window)
window.collectionBehavior = .fullScreenAuxiliary
window_controller?.showWindow(self)
window.toggleFullScreen(true)
```

Has anyone had any luck with this?

**Edit 1:**

I added this line:

```
NSApp.presentationOptions = [.fullScreen, .hideDock, .autoHideMenuBar]
```

and I got this warning:

```
setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
```

**Edit 2:**

I switched to this method:

[HOWTO: Create a Locked Down Fullscreen Cocoa Application and Implement NSLayoutConstraints using Swift](https://blogs.wcode.org/2015/06/howto-create-a-locked-down-fullscreen-cocoa-application-and-implement-nslayoutconstraints-using-swift/)

```
let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar]
let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: NSNumber(value: presOptions.rawValue)]
self.fullscreen_view?.enterFullScreenMode((NSScreen.screens()?[1])!, withOptions: optionsDictionary)
```

The view goes fullscreen tho not showing the content, just grey.

**Edit 3:**

I turned NSFullScreenModeAllScreens off and now it kinda works:

```
let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: NSNumber(value: presOptions.rawValue), NSFullScreenModeAllScreens: false]
```

The only thing now is that the menu bar and dock don't show up on the first screen.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884669/fullscreen-nswindow-on-secondary-monitor-swift?rq=1 ?

Comment: tried all the answers there without luck on 10.12

Answer (score 0):

For me, `enterFullScreenMode` seems to only work properly if called after the view "is shown" already.

It works if I call it inside the `func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) { /* here */ }` (or also by using a `Timer.scheduledTimer`).